# Simple explanation for this optparse example from Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line, optparse

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"

  opts.on("-v", "--[no-]verbose", "Run verbosely") do |v|
    options[:verbose] = v
  end
end.parse!

p options
p ARGV
```

I found this from the optparse documentation page [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html). Can someone please explain this example in layman terms? I read the documentation but, there are some parts I don't understand. Namely, the `end.parse!` and the difference between the methods `parse` and `permute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `end.parse!` is not some magical kind of `end` if that's what you were thinking. It can be written like this:

```
option_parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"

  opts.on("-v", "--[no-]verbose", "Run verbosely") do |v|
    options[:verbose] = v
  end
end

option_parser.parse!
```

Comment: Just for clarification, what does "parse!" do?

Comment: @Practical1: splits the command line string and tries to match the parts to what you configured. If a match is found, it calls the provided handler.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, but just one more question: "What's the difference between "parse" and "permute"?

Comment: @Practical1: not sure, never used permute.

Answer (score 2):

As [Sergio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52653599/4794) explains, the `end.parse!` is creating an anonymous object and calling `parse!` on it. However, you also asked about `parse` vs. `permute`.

From reading the documentation, it looks like there are two ways to consume an array of command-line arguments: strictly in order, or in any legal permutation. There are three relevant methods on the `OptionParser` class:

- `order!` - parse the arguments in order until you get to a positional argument
- `permute!` - parse all the arguments, skipping over positional ones
- `parse!` - call `order!` if the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable is set, otherwise call `permute!`

All three leave unconsumed arguments in `ARGV`, or whatever array you pass in, as well as returning the unconsumed arguments. There are also three equivalent methods with the exclamation point removed. These work on a copy of the array, so the original is unchanged.

Here's your original script in `example.rb`, called with optional arguments before and after positional ones:

```
$ ruby example.rb -v foo bar
{:verbose=>true}
["foo", "bar"]
$ ruby example.rb foo -v bar
{:verbose=>true}
["foo", "bar"]
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 ruby example.rb foo -v bar
{}
["foo", "-v", "bar"]
$
```

Now, I change `end.parse!` to `end.order!`:

```
$ ruby example.rb -v foo bar
{:verbose=>true}
["foo", "bar"]
$ ruby example.rb foo -v bar
{}
["foo", "-v", "bar"]
$
```

Changing it to `end.permute!`:

```
$ ruby example.rb -v foo bar
{:verbose=>true}
["foo", "bar"]
$ ruby example.rb foo -v bar
{:verbose=>true}
["foo", "bar"]
$
```

This can also affect when the script will complain about unknown options. Your script only has a `-v` option, not a `-x` option, so it will complain if it tries to parse `-x`. If you don't want it to complain, you have a few options:

- Catch the error in the script and deal with it.
- Put `-x` after a positional argument, and parse arguments in order.
- Put `--` in the command line somewhere before `-x`. `--` tells the parser to stop parsing options and pass all the rest as positional arguments.

Here's another example with your original script:

```
$ ruby example.rb -v foo -x bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
example.rb:10:in `<main>': invalid option: x (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
example.rb:10:in `<main>': invalid option: -x (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 ruby example.rb -v foo -x bar
{:verbose=>true}
["foo", "-x", "bar"]
$ ruby example.rb -v -- -x foo bar
{:verbose=>true}
["-x", "foo", "bar"]
$
```